# How to increase size of something in class, but not other elements in class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have four images inside a div. they all have a width of 5.5%

[_o__o__o__o_]

I want to use javascript to change the target that is moused over (hovered on), and have it look like this:

[_o__O__o__o_]

so I made the width of the target increase
however it also pushes the other elements to the side instead of staying where they are so it's more like:

[_o___O___o__o_]

I don't know how to make the other elements stay exactly where they are instead of being pushed.

The issue is that YES I am successfully able to alter the width.
BUT changing the width of one element pushes the surrounding elements to the respective right and left.
jsbin: https://jsbin.com/zujutamazo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: show the code you have... use jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: my code won't run on jsfiddle because I rely on a for loop to change my *local* pictures that go img1, img2, img3, etc.

Comment: just use placholder pictures like http://placekitten.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was explaining, you need to set a higher z-index to "be above" the non-hovered boxes. And set negative left-right margins, equivalent to the additional width from hovering to prevent everything from moving around.

Below is a working example, with percentages.

```css
body {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
     }
     
 .myClass {
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;   
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .myClass:hover {
    width: 30%;
    height: 70%;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0 -5%;
  }
  
  body .myClass:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  body .myClass:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  body .myClass:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
  body .myClass:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 
 </head>    
 <body>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
  <div class="myClass"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I realize I can do this with hover, but I am choosing not to because I'm relying on the change to be implemented into other javascript functions. Your answer does not address the problem I'm having.

Comment: You'll need to use the `onmouseover` event to trigger your javascript function. and `onmouseout` to reset the styling.

Comment: I realize this- again, not the issue I'm haivng. Using onmouseover isn't the problem, the problem is with the css. I can successfully change the width from 5.5% to 9%, and it *works*, but the other elements change their position as a result, which seems to be a css issue.

Comment: thats why on hover I've added a negative margin, to compensate the size increase and not affect the other images. So the proposed CSS should fix your issue, only you don't need the `.myClass:hover` case, since you're handling styles with javascript.

Comment: changing the margin doesn't help

Comment: also I've done my width in percent so maybe that's why?

Comment: I've added a working example with the same styling as before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this one:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
        width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.item1 { background-color: blue; } 
.item2 { background-color: red; } 
.item3 { background-color: orange; } 
.item4 { background-color: yellow; } 

.item:hover .circle{
  background-color: black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="item item1">
       <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
 <div class="item item2">
       <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
 <div class="item item3">
       <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
 <div class="item item4">
       <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't the other three getting smaller and the sides move out when hovering over red/orange.

Comment: exactly^ i need the other three to stay the same

Comment: when i mouse over the red element, for example, the right edge of the orange box shifts to the right. I want it to remain the same